# How do I paginate through results returned by foursquare venues / search api?

Tags: api, pagination, geocoding, foursquare

I want to create a list of all restaurants within a given lat-long boundary. I'm using foursquare venues/search API for the same, with *sw* & *ne* parameters.

If I'm expecting, say, 200 results. I know each limit caps at 50 results and I'm OKAY to perform 4 requests with +50 offset.
But I get the same set of results when [limit=50, offset=50] and [limit=50, offset=100]

Here are the params in the sample GET request:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=blaa&client_secret=blaa2&v=20190610&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&limit=50&sw=40.467632,-74.292252&ne=40.935656,-73.672914&intent=browse&offset=50

Answer (score 1):

According to Foursquare's [documentation for venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search), there is no offset parameter. You probably want to use [the venues/explore endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/explore) along with the `&section=food` parameter (instead of the `categoryId` parameter).

Comment: Thanks, but does /explore API support boundaries in terms of SW and NE?